# How is the PATH variable defined for the vscode process itself (not the integrated terminal)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pipenv, vscode-remote

I'm currently using a vscode over a remote ssh connection and cannot figure out how to set the search PATH for the vscode process itself. I have set the `PATH` for processes run in the terminal in my `.bashrc` file, which is also sourced from `.bash_profile`.

In spite of this, vscode complains that `pipenv` is not on the path although it is visible to my integrated terminal session. In my `.bashrc` I am loading environment modules to load versions of needed libraries, which get put on the `PATH`. Since I created my `virtualenv` using `pipenv` in the terminal, it knows which `python` version to use and makes a link to it in the environment definition. Because of the way `python` virtual environments work, the actual `python` binary is copied to the virtual environment. And because vscode has hardcoded paths where to look for virtual environments it is able to find the correct version of python that is in use (despite it not seeing it in the `PATH`).

In addition, hardcoding the path to `pipenv` using the extension setting `python.pipenvPath` still produces a "not found" error.

Solutions that I have seen elsewhere suggest launching vscode from the command line so that the process inherits the `PATH` settings. However, this will not work over a remote connection.